# Print a web page with fixed header and footer (that hide some data)

Tags: html, css

I have a web page like this one (simplified):

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
        ....
        </div>
        <div id="header">
        ....
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        ....
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Header and Footer are fixed (top and bottom), the Content has overflow auto.
At screen no problem.
When I try to print the document (some pages), some part of the content is hidden in every page by the two bands of Header and Footer (that must be printed too).
I searched in the Internet, but I don't understand if there is a solution to my question... 
Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

[missing text in page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My7WG.jpg)

Comment: Can you paste a print of the problem?

Comment: Not saying the best solution but there are some of the frameworks that lets you render your page to pdf. Then print the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Just put an `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to content. So if you have:

```
#header{
  height:5vh;
}
#footer{
  height:7vh;
}
```

you would do:

```
#content{
  margin-top:5vh;
  margin-bottom:7vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check wether the CSS rules applies only for your front-page or for the whole website. And if it doesn't work, give us a printscreen with the problem!